# adding quantity_inputs after woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link hook without calling it

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I added a code in function.php to add quantity section after add to cart in all pages.

But I don't want to add it also in wishlist page,

So I make it like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if (!is_page('wishlist')) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        // Access the cart items
        $in_cart = false;
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
            if($product_id == $product->get_ID()){
                $in_cart = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If we have match update quantity
        if($in_cart) {
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array('input_value' => $quantity), $product, false );
        } else {
            $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        }
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
}
```

**It works, but the problem is it remove add to cart button on wishlist page**

What I'm doing wrong?
Can I do it without calling woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link hook

Because if I remove it from filter, the button appear again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `return $html;` at the bottom like this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if (!is_page('wishlist')) {
        if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
            $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            // Access the cart items
            $in_cart = false;
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
                $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
                if($product_id == $product->get_ID()){
                    $in_cart = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If we have match update quantity
            if($in_cart) {
                $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array('input_value' => $quantity), $product, false );
            } else {
                $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
            }
            $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
            $html .= '</form>';
        }
        return $html;
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You can remove the top return $html; though, the bottom one would return its content anyways.